# selecting one duplicate from re-occurances with only one varying colum SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, sybase

```
Current State
id | val | varchar_id| uid
----------------------
1  | 1   |  A4D        NEWID()
1  | 2   |  A3G        NEWID()
2  | 1   |  7S3        NEWID()
2  | 1   |  43E        NEWID()
2  | 2   |  7S3        NEWID()
2  | 2   |  431        NEWID()
3  | 1   |  432        NEWID()
3  | 2   |  43P        NEWID()

Ideal state
id | val | varchar_id|
----------------------
1  | 1   |  A4D        NEWID()
1  | 2   |  A3G        NEWID()
2  | 1   |  7S3        NEWID()
2  | 2   |  7S3        NEWID()
3  | 1   |  432        NEWID()
3  | 2   |  43P        NEWID()
```

Removing of duplicate occurrences of id + val

I have tried (pseudo code below):

```
SELECT *
from table 
WHERE uid = MAX
GROUP BY id, val
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this/ am I missing something here? I do not mind which of the duplicates are returned.

Also, the version of Sybase I am using does not allow Partition x over x,y functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using SQL you can do it this way. Also your where clause isn't what SQL supports.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Val INT, V_ID VARCHAR(50), uidd UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,1,'A4D',NEWID()),
(1,2,'A3G',NEWID()),
(2,1,'7S3',NEWID()),
(2,2,'43E',NEWID()),
(2,2,'7S3',NEWID()),
(2,2,'431',NEWID()),
(3,1,'432',NEWID()),
(3,2,'43P',NEWID())

SELECT t.id, t.Val, MAX(V_ID) AS varchar_id, MAX(uidd) 
FROM @T AS t 
GROUP BY id, val
ORDER BY id, val
```

This will give you the result

```
+---+----+-----------+-------------------------------------+
|id |Val |varchar_id |uid                                  |
+---+----+-----------+-------------------------------------+
|1  |1   |A4D        |5296ACE4-573A-4A7E-882F-516EA8E9DBDD |
|1  |2   |A3G        |3EE82BEE-8C18-4415-BB3D-110F443409B5 |
|2  |1   |7S3        |68DBF7B3-316D-4A8B-B8AD-8825EC83585D |
|2  |2   |7S3        |01C54277-7156-47E1-9205-DD577A726196 |
|3  |1   |432        |6F53F332-FC9C-4EE1-A3D2-1D0FD002DDAF |
|3  |2   |43P        |7B532EBD-E6C9-4BE4-B0F7-FCBCB9CE1D61 |
+---+----+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this Kevin :)

The where clause, I typed MAX to save me typing out a sub select for selecting MAX as it is out of scope for the problem, trying to keep the question free of bloating :D

Comment: `MAX(V_ID), MAX(uidd) ` - these two MAX can give values from two completely different records (rows). Asker may be surprised, since she (probably) wanted to pick one row, not two values from two rows ;)

Comment: @krokodilko I'm a guy :') , also noted, will apply to my data set and configure for what I am after :D